# Main Controller checks login and loop redirecting(codeigniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter

My Main Controller checks wheter the **user is admin** or not, then redirects to a **user/login** which is a child class of the main controller who again checks if the user is an **admin or not**...so then the redirect is **in loop**, I don't know where better to put the login function?

```
Admin_Controller -> {

  child1_Controller -> {

    function login()
    {
       //render login page, but can't because the main class constructor is checking login and redirecting again here

    }

  } 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at running a pre_controller hook to check the user details instead of using the constructor

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/hooks.html

Comment: but the hooks are global, i want to use it only when the admin controllers are executed

Comment: There are two ways you could handle that, either in your hook do a simple check on the URI. if ($this->uri->segment(1) === 'admin') or you would have to pull the login form action out of the controller that is doing the check